# Consulta select PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php  
require("config.inc.php");
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(!empty($_POST))
{
        if(empty($_POST['usuario_rut_administrador']))
        {        
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Por favor  rellene todos los campos solicitados";
            die(json_encode($response));
         }

        $sql = "SELECT id_estacionamiento, nombre_estacionamiento, cantidad_cupos 
        FROM estacionamiento where usuario_rut_administrador=:usuariorutadministrador";

        $query_params= array(':usuariorutadministrador' =>$_POST['usuario_rut_administrador']);

        try{
              $stmt   = $db->prepare($sql);
              $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }  catch (PDOException $ex) {             
              $response["success"] = 0;
              $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
              die(json_encode($response));
        }    

        $resulta = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($resulta->num_rows >0) {
              while($row[] = $resulta->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $tem = $row;
                    $json = json_encode($tem);
               }
               echo $json;
        }
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if ($row) {
               $response["success"] = 0;
               $response["message"] = "si existe";
               die(json_encode($response));
        }
```

recibo una variable por post la cual veo si se encuentra vacía o no, luego con esa variable quiero realizar el select para que me muestre los datos relacionados a la variable , pero, aquí esta el problema por que no me muestra ningún dato ni nada, solo queda en blanco.

al realizar un `SELECT * FROM estacionamiento` si me muestra los datos, así que debe ser un problema con la variable, pero no se que puede ser. 
espero puedan ayudarme gracias :)

Comment: Prueba poniendo un "var_dump($_POST['usuario_rut_administrador']);" abajo de "if(!empty($_POST)){", comentas que te devuelve.

Comment: me devuelve esto "string(4) "1111" {"success":0,"message":"si existe"}"

Comment: y sin var_dump muestra solo esto "{"success":0,"message":"si existe"}"

Comment: Por qué en tu json_encode usas die(), cámbialo por echo en ambas partes

Comment: ¿Estás usando `mysqli`  ... `$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);`  o bien `PDO` ... `}  catch (PDOException $ex) {`?  Tenía una respuesta casi lista cuando me encuentro con esa grave divergencia en tu código. Hay más problemas, como *marear* los resultados al final, como si no tuvieras claro qué quieres hacer con los resultados de la base de datos.